# In MOSS 2007, what does event ID 6644 means?

Tags: error, event-receivers

In SharePoint 2010, [6644](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff382635%28v=office.14%29.aspx) refers to error related to Event Receiver. In MOSS 2007, is this the same? MSDN doesn't specified what type of error this event id refers to.

In the event log, I got the following, multiple times

```
Event Type: Error
Event Source:   Windows SharePoint Services 3
Event Category: General 
Event ID:   6644
Date:       12/7/2012
Time:       4:10:58 AM
User:       N/A
Computer:   xxxxxxxxxxxx
Description:
Event manager error: Could not load file or 
assembly 'xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxx, Version=2.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=123456789abcdef' 
or one of its dependencies. The system cannot 
find the file specified.

For more information, see Help and Support Center 
at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
```

Comment: it it a custom event receiver I think? are all the dlls in your GAC? Maybe have you release a feature with a event receiver that looking for a dll that you have no more?

Comment: Well, the deployment of the dll went from 1.x to 3.x, skipping 2.x. I'm not sure if this type of error comes from event receivers calling for particular version of dll

Comment: IMHO you can have this problem for two at least: a) the xml that map your event to your dll is wrog; or b) you haven't the dll deployed on your GAC.
What about the dev environment?

Comment: 3.x of the dll is deployed. What I wondered is why the some process (event receivers?) is looking for 2.x which was never deployed. Anyway, how do i check the deployed xml that maps to the dll?

Comment: check on the feature directory

Comment: have you run an iisreset after the installtion?

Comment: I think the SP package installation through `stsadm` restarts the IIS.

Comment: yes it does, so maybe the problem was a old version on your gac library

Comment: I don't think there's any problem with the old library. BTW, here's the link to the batch file I used to uninstall the SP Package (https://gist.github.com/OnesimusUnbound/4730213). I not sure if there's problem with it.

Comment: `... so maybe the problem was a old version on your gac library` Thanks for suggesting this. I checked the feature deactivation of the code and it only deletes one event receivers at SP Web, instead of processing all event receivers candidate for deletion.

Comment: make the comment useful ;)